# Как запустить команды Git из Java?

Tags: java, git

Я могу запускать команды, `git add`, `git commit`, прямо из Git. Но есть ли какие-либо методы, чтобы я мог запускать команды непосредственно из java.

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git add");`

Comment: Добавил в ответ ссылку на описание методов на русском, для возможно более простого ознакомление с классом Runtime

Comment: https://eclipse.org/jgit/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не знаю как это описать на русском. Но в *Java* есть класс **[Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)** для соответствующей работы.

У него есть метод `getRuntime()`, который возвращает соответствующий приложению `Runtime`, а также есть метод `exec(String command)`, который в отдельном процессе запускает команду, представленную переданной строкой. Возвращаемый объект `:py:class::java.lang.Process` и может быть использован для управления выполнением этого процесса. Собственно их и можно использовать. Пример:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git add");
```

Естественно с `try/catch` и прочими проверяющими конструкциями

---

P.S.

Нашел описание методов на русском, чтоб ознакомиться проще было. Источник **[ilnurgi1.ru](http://www.ilnurgi1.ru/docs/java/java/lang/Runtime.html)**:

*class java.lang.Runtime*

**getRuntime()** - 
Возвращает соответсвующий приложению Runtime

**exit(int status)** *public void* - 
Осуществляет завершение программы с кодом завершения status (при использовании этого метода особое внимание нужно уделить обработке исключений - выход будет осуществлен моментально, и в конструкциях try-catch-finally управление в finally передано не будет)

**gc()** *public native void* - Сигнализирует сборщику мусора о необходимости запуска

**freeMemory()** *public native long* - Возвращает количество свободной памяти. В некоторых случаях это количество может быть увеличено, если вызвать у объекта Runtime метод gc()

**totalMemory()** *public native long* - Возвращает суммарное количество памяти, выделенное Java машине. Это количество может из изменяться даже в течении одного запуска, что зависит от реализации платформы на которой запущена Java машина. Так-же, не стоит закладываться на объем памяти, занимаемой одним определенным объектом - эта величина так же зависит от реализации Java машины.

**loadLibrary(String libname)** *public void* - Загружает библиотеку с указанным именем. Обычно загрузка библиотек производится следующим образом: в классе, использующем native реализации методов, добавляется статический инициализатор, например:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("LibFile");
}
```

Таким образом, когда класс будет загружен и инициализирован, необходимый код для реализации native методов так-же будет загружен. Если будет произведено несколько вызовов загрузки библиотеки с одним и тем-же именем - произведен будет только первый, а все остальные будут проигнорированы.

**load(String filename)** *public void* - Подгружает файл с указанным названием в качестве библиотеки. В принципе, этот метод работает так-же как и метод load(), только принимает в качестве параметра именно название файла, а не библиотеки, тем самым позволяя загрузить любой файл с native кодом.

**runFinalization()** *public void* - Производит запуск выполнения методов finalize() у всех объектов, этого ожидающих

**exec(String command)** *public Process* - В отдельном процессе запускает команду, представленную переданной строкой. Возвращаемый объект :py:class::java.lang.Process может быть использован для управления выполнением этого процесса.